# Thumbnail in the new order e-mails

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, order-email, thumbnail

I'd like to show the product thumbnail in the new orders emails.
I tried this code:

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage:: getThumbnail('catalog/product_media_config')
             ->getMediaUrl($_product->getThumbnail()); ?>" alt="<?php echo $_item->getName() ?>" />
```

It doesn't work. Any helps?

Comment: I wouldn't do that if I were you. The minute you flush your Catalog Image Cache, every thumbnail in any newsletter will became invalid.

Comment: Is this the same issue as this one http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/165940/new-order-email-missing-product-image-layout-handle-sales-email-order-items

Answer (score 3):

For thumbanil it is compulsory to select thumbnail image at back end other wise you get default image

you can fetch main image and resize that image for your requirement

```
 <?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize($size)->__toString(); // here $size is your image size ?>
```

Try below solution may it works

```
$backendModel = $collection->getResource()->getAttribute('media_gallery')->getBackend();
 $backendModel->afterLoad($_product);
```

and then try below code

```
 <?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize($size)->__toString(); // here $size is your image size ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing your code,

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($_product->getThumbnail()); ?>"  width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $_item->getName() ?>" />
```

to

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(135)->__toString(); ?>"  width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $_item->getName() ?>" />
```

You can use `thumbnail` or `image` or `small_image`.
Refresh your Image Cache.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you should detail a little bit more your question, e.g. I don't know where did you place the code you mention. Anyway, have you tried to do this:

In the file

```
app/design/frontend/your-package/your-theme/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
```

which should be based on

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
```

you can place this code after `<?php $_order = $this->getItem()->getorder(); ?>`

```
<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId($_item->getOrder()->getStoreId())
            ->load($_item->getProductId());?>
```

and then, wherever you want to place your product image you should place

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')
             ->getMediaUrl($_product->getThumbnail()); ?>" 
             alt="<?php echo $_item->getName() ?>" />
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: i tried this but not working please see this link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/165940/new-order-email-missing-product-image-layout-handle-sales-email-order-items