# New order email missing product image {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}

Tags: magento-1.8, email-templates

The new order email template is rendering everything except the product image of the order.

This is how the template was trying to call it by default, which doesn't work:

`{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}`

This is the error:

[image]

Can anyone advise on what might be the problem.

This is the function i worte:

`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml`

```
if ($_item->getProductType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE) {
    $parentId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                       ->getParentIdsByChild($_item->getProductId());  
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')  
                       ->setStoreId($_item->getOrder()->getStoreId())  
                       ->load($parentId);
} else {
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')  
                       ->setStoreId($_item->getOrder()->getStoreId())  
                       ->load($_item->getProductId());  
}

?>
```

this is display code:

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')  
                        ->getMediaUrl($_product->getThumbnail()); ?>"  width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $_item->getName() ?>" />
```

Comment: No one know this

Comment: Can you see value for `src` in your email when you inspect?

Comment: Oh god thank you for replay @JaiminSutariya. Yeah i see the value of `src` this is that `https://www.domain.in/media/catalog/product/` ( for eg: www.domain.in)

Comment: Did you try with `echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(135)->__toString();` as your image src value?

Comment: Yeah working but image does not exit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you get it working yet? I think the reason for product showing wrong image is this function written in

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml

The mentioned code, checks for configurable product and then tries to get its parent ids. It should be the other way round. Check this edited code

```
if ($_item->getProductType() !== Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE) {
    $parentIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                       ->getParentIdsByChild($_item->getProductId());  
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')  
                       ->setStoreId($_item->getOrder()->getStoreId())  
                       ->load($parentIds[0]);
} else {
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')  
                       ->setStoreId($_item->getOrder()->getStoreId())  
                       ->load($_item->getProductId());  
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Its working but in bundle product order it's not working. Any way thank you mskhan

Comment: Glad to know that. Cheers!! :)

Comment: Any solution for bundle products...?

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing your code,

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($_product->getThumbnail()); ?>"  width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $_item->getName() ?>" />
```

to

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(135)->__toString(); ?>"  width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $_item->getName() ?>" />
```

Comment: It's working but showing wrong image like Image does not exit image

Comment: can you confirm if thumbnail image is added. or you can use `small_image` instead of `thumbnail`

Comment: I checked in admin panel `catalog->manage products->productname->` in **product information** images section selected `thumbnail`

Comment: you can also try adding `image` in place of `thumbnail` as @murtuza suggested.

Comment: Ya i tried both Jaimin image showing but that's image not product image see this link  you will understand [image](https://www.mirrorwhite.in/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/135x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/placeholder/default/image-not-ex_6.jpg)

Comment: The reason for not showing image can only be that the product does not have image selected in its detail page. Try refreshing your image cache from admin.

Comment: Jaimin if am refreshing image cache any chance to delete image or something happen because my site in live

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55953/discussion-between-jaimin-sutariya-and-ramesh-s).

Comment: refreshing image cache same problem

Answer (score 2):

For thumbanil it is compulsory to select thumbnail image at back end other wise you get default image

you can fetch main image and resize that image for your requirement

```
 <?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize($size)->__toString(); // here $size is your image size ?>
```

Try below solution may it works

```
$backendModel = $collection->getResource()->getAttribute('media_gallery')->getBackend();
 $backendModel->afterLoad($_product);
```

and then try below code

```
 <?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize($size)->__toString(); // here $size is your image size ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Murtuza Zabuawala image showing but that image not product image see this link [image](https://www.mirrorwhite.in/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/135x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/placeholder/default/image-not-ex_6.jpg)

Comment: @RameshS  in your code replace `thumnail` to `image` and try and also do reindexing

Comment: This is the code `<img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(135)->__toString(); ?>"  width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $_item->getName() ?>" />` is this right..?

Comment: @RameshS see updated answer

Comment: Its showing same image now im try to clear image cache in admin. But your ans also right. Any possible for select two ans in magento.stack overflow

Comment: @RameshS there is no  way to select two answer

Comment: @RameshS I have just answerd at here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106768/thumbnail-in-the-new-order-e-mails